# How do I check the Received Length of serial data packet is correct or not?

Tags: serial-port, communication, uart

I want to send data through serial ,my format is Start_flag,Length,data,CheckSum so its 0xAA,0x05,M,T,O,N,0x78
On the receiver after it gets start flag then it receive 5(len) data.
I want to confirm whether the Length received is correct or not? then I go for data receive.Because If I get length as 4 it creates Error. Can anyone help me Please.....

Comment: You'll have to assume it is correct.  If it is not then you won't find out until later.  Either because of a timeout (too large) or because the checksum doesn't match (too small).

Comment: thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

simlply create state machine to handle and counte the incoming bytes.
take into account corrupted length byte.
in addtion ,reset the state machine in case of timeout.